# How to create custom page template in folder

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template, joomla-article

If I want a page that pulls product information (like an iPhone) from the server, how do I create a new page template for it and link it back to the main page?  I don't need to create a new template directory. I just want to create a page that lists a product in a very specific way.

You can do it easily in Wordpress(http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), but it's near impossible in Joomla without jumping through hoops!

Edit:
What I am talking about is how to add different page layouts for something I call a product page and then having a main page(index.php).  Essentially, is there a way to have two template layouts in one template file? It seems so wasteful to have to create a new template directory if I want to tweak the layout of simple pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "pull product information", but this is how you create new "pages"

To create new "pages", all you need to do is create a new article. To do this go to:

```
Joomla Backend >> Content >> Article Manager >> New
```

then you need to create a new menu item. To do this go to:

```
Joomla Backend >> Menus >> Main Menu (optional) >> New
```

and link the menu item to the article you created.

If there is something more specific you need to suit your needs, try on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/)

Comment: @Leon: what do you mean by "templating"? what is it exactly you are trying to acheive. I'm a little confused. Also, why did you decide to go with Joomla instead of Wordpress if you find it really easy?

Comment: When I say templating I mean creating custom pages and getting the variables to output so I can style the page how I want. Im an independent programmer who is trying to learn all the cms's for contract work.  This by far is the most frustrating